# With templates, how to differentiate two parallel cases, such as between floating point types and integral types?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

cppreference.com ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if#Notes ) notes that:

> A common mistake is to declare two function templates that differ only in their default template arguments. This is illegal because default template arguments are not part of function template's signature, and declaring two different function templates with the same signature is illegal.
>
> ```
> struct T {
>     enum { int_t,float_t } m_type;
>     template <typename Integer,
>               typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integer>::value>
>     >
>     T(Integer) : m_type(int_t) {}
>  
>     template <typename Floating,
>               typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<Floating>::value>
>     >
>     T(Floating) : m_type(float_t) {} // error: cannot overload
> };
> ```

So true… So what is the correct approach to solve this issue and actually achieve what the above incorrect code fails to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

I believe this would work:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct T {
    enum { int_t,float_t } m_type;
    template <typename Integer,
              std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integer>::value>* = nullptr
    >
    T(Integer) : m_type(int_t) {}

    template <typename Floating,
              std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<Floating>::value>* = nullptr
    >
    T(Floating) : m_type(float_t) {} // now the overload is valid
};

int main() {
    T t = int{};
    T t2 = float{};
    (void)t;
    (void)t2;
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Rz2glrwEltIBUfey)

Answer (score 4):

Use tag dispatching:

```
namespace tag
{
struct floating{};
struct integer{};
struct error{};

template<typename T, typename = void> struct get : error {};

template<typename T>
struct get<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>> : integer {};

template<typename T>
struct get<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>> : floating {};

}

struct Foo
{
    template<typename T>
    Foo(T&&, tag::floating){
    }

    template<typename T>
    Foo(T&&, tag::integer){
    }

    template<typename T>
    Foo(T&& t) : Foo(std::forward<T>(t), tag::get<std::decay_t<T>>{}) {}
};
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/VTuOBbDb54JRJRaW)

Comment: This seems awkward if every time a method is called, we have to manually pass a tag that tells C++ that `float` is a floating point type and `int` is an integral type… Wouldn’t it be better to let C++ sort this out itself?

Comment: @gaazkam Well, it's an established and very flexible idiom in C++ (just look at `iterator_traits`). For example, you can employ the overload resolution mechanism to select the overload you want with the option to fall back to a more generic one if you structure your tags into a hierarchy (again, you can provide overloads for `random_iterator_tag` and `bidirectional_iterator_tag`). Also extending this approach if you want to support another group of types is much easier than it is with a nest of enable ifs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `enable_if` in another dummy argument in constructor's parameter list:

```
struct T {
    enum { int_t,float_t } m_type;

    template <typename Integer>
    T(Integer, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integer>::value>* = nullptr)
        : m_type(int_t) {}

    template <typename Floating>
    T(Floating, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<Floating>::value>* = nullptr)
        : m_type(float_t) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a yet another way to sort this out. This sadly won’t work with floats due to the limitations of the use of floating point types within templates, but should work for most other cases nevertheless (such as differentiating between signed and unsigned types):

```
struct T {
    enum { signed_t,unsigned_t } m_type;
    template <typename Signed,
              std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed<Signed>::value, bool> = true
    >
    T(Signed) : m_type(signed_t) {}

    template <typename Unsigned,
              std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<Unsigned>::value, bool> = true
    >
    T(Unsigned) : m_type(unsigned_t) {}
};
```

Live example: http://ideone.com/xqp4nd

Comment: You don't have to use different return types for `std::enable_if_t`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Err, otherwise I’ll fall for the problem stated in my question, won’t I?

Comment: No, Even if you remove default, you still have different type: `std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed<T>::value>` vs `std::enable_if_t<std::is_unsigned<T>::value>`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Better now? I can’t leave the default `void` though, I think.